# Where do I ask a question about a company's goal for example?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Let's say a company did something, and I want to know *why*, where do I ask it? For example, I was going to ask this on Super User but I realized it was out of place:

> Windows 10 was said to be **free**, but now they've taken into account that that's not true; as past July 29 2016 it will no longer be
>   that way.
>
> So why did Microsoft do this? How would it help filling their wallets?
>   What was there goal in giving us a free year?
>
> I mean, was their goal to get their OS popular and more famous with
>   the statistics as *"The Most Used OS"*? Or did they just be kind or
>   something?

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Comment: When your entire question is based on an invalid premise, it's not really on topic anywhere.

Comment: You might have [better luck at Quora](https://www.quora.com/Microsoft-doesnt-give-things-away-without-a-strategy-Why-are-they-pushing-Windows-10-so-forcefully) (44 answers!). These kind of questions are even part of their original DNA, I think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ask Microsoft.

Stack Exchange works really well for technical support, but our third-party support of these products and services **does not extend to providing *customer support*** for these companies. Generally speaking, questions involving

- feature requests
- bug reports
- strategic and future-direction discussions
- business inquiries

and other customer support issues should be handled by the companies who are able to answer those types of questions directly. The best our users can hope to offer is random anecdotes and hearsay, so that's why these questions don't generally fit our Q&A model — they will usually be **closed as 'off topic'** by just about every community.

Comment: So when will we have microsoft.stackexchange.com? ;)

Answer (score 6):

I fear that this is not a good question for *any* site in the Stack Exchange network. Answers to these kind of questions tend to be really opinionated, and maybe the only definitive answer can be given by C-level Microsoft officers, not by the Stack Exchange community. If you know how to contact them, ask them directly.

For reference, here is the close reason which is often used for these kind of questions (emphasis mine):

> #### primarily opinion-based
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than **facts**, **references**, or specific expertise.

Comment: I asked what they THINK there goal was, they should list the possibilities, or simply state facts and conclude something.

Comment: @AbAppletic Think == Opinion based

Comment: You'll get loads of speculation and conjecture over on http://quora.com (which is ok and often fun). It's not in line with SE's goals though