# Where to ask about business models or computer applications?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Specifically, I am wondering why Spotify doesn't have an option to skip explicit songs. It it too difficult to implement? Are they afraid they'll lose money if they do?

A site that covers computer applications would do. Otherwise the topic could depend on the answer - if Spotify cannot add the feature because of a programming issue, then it would fit a computer science site. If Spotify does not add the feature because of their business model, then it would fit a business site.

Comment: And the only people who could answer is... spotify.

Comment: see also: [Where do I ask a question about a company's goal for example?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281482/165773)

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the point of asking a question on any specific site is - finding the right people, the experts so to speak.

The only people who know why spotify does this is - spotify, and I'm pretty doubtful they'd go "we do this because foo" - especially where this is pretty much a feature request contorted into a question.

I *suppose* "can I set a explicit song filter in spotify?" might work as a question on webapps, but the why's unlikely to be a good fit anywhere.